# Guice ServeContextListener does not kick-in

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to do a `@Named` inject for a bound String in the `ServeContextListener`, however I always get that the String is not bound exception. So I guess the `ServeContextListener` does not kick in.

This is my **web.xml** configuration:

```
<!-- GAE-Shiro -->

<context-param>
   <param-name>user-base-url</param-name>
   <param-value>/user/admin</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>static-base-url</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.guice.ServeContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>   

<!-- JBoss Resteasy -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.guice.ServeModule</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>  
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>  
    <param-value>/</param-value>  
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The actual binding is in the `ServeLogic`:

```
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServeLogic(userBaseUrl, staticBaseUrl), new ServeModule(userBaseUrl));
}
```

The only ones that gets bound are those in the `resteasy.guice.modules`:

```
org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.guice.ServeModule
```

Why is that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual stacktrace. I skimmed the web.xml and it looks correct.

Comment: @ilikeorangutans I have solved this issue, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this isssue by:

- Extending GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener and combine ServeContextListener to it.
- This way the app only have one Context Listener which is GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener

Thus I have only this listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.guice.CustomGuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Hello xybrek, can you add to the answer correct web.xml. Thank you.